# Select a directory in a Codename One desktop app

Tags: codenameone

My Codename One desktop app for Windows needs to select a file to read it and select a directory where to save a file.

The first requirement is easily solved by the “File Chooser” cn1lib.

But how can my app allow the user to select a directory to save a file? If a native interface is required, can you please show me an example of code? I never wrote a native interface for Windows. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native interface for a desktop app would be implemented in Java. So you can write Swing/AWT FileChooser/JFileChooser code to pick a file.